# How do I use the Mythbuntu repository on a headless server?

Tags: ppa, mythbuntu, mythtv

I would like to set up my server to use the Mythbuntu repositories to keep MythTV more up to date than the version in the offical Ubuntu repositories.

I know I can install `mythbuntu-control-centre` on my server and access it from another computer using `ssh -X`, but I would like to avoid using the graphical interface entirely if I can.

So how do configure my server to use the Mythbuntu repos without using a GUI?

Comment: got a simple answer on irc, THANKS!  apt-add-repository ppa:mythbuntu/0.26

Answer (score 3):

The way we do the repos is by MythTV major version number, and the command to add it would be

`apt-add-repository ppa:mythbuntu/<MythTV Version number>`

So for 0.26 it would be

`apt-add-repository ppa:mythbuntu/0.26`

Note that any point releases (such as 0.26.1) would still be the 0.26 version.